# Loop required for Web Query and error handler

Tags: vba, web-services, excel, excel-2010

I have list of MAC ID's. I tried to find all the vendor details. I tried for one but i need it till the end in column A(Where all the MAC ID I mentioned). If it will not found then simply skip and it has to move to next loop and paste below. I did it for one.

```
Sub FindMACTest()

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=" & Range("A1"), Destination:=Range _
        ("$I$1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "1"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I hope few mac id i can provide:F4-F5-A5-DF-DD-92
A4-17-31-EA-D4-11
B4-52-7D-E6-D3-EB
68-9C-5E-7B-9D-EE
74-F0-6D-46-0F-E8
0C-14-20-8D-FE-C9
C0-CB-38-4C-25-5B
B0-EE-45-07-42-CA
B8-76-3F-E4-F9-93
C4-17-FE-D5-94-11
8C-3A-E3-95-9F-C2
D0-B3-3F-DE-A0-E9
24-FD-52-4E-60-F1
E2-D7-4A-51-93-71
D0-C1-B1-DD-33-A6
20-54-76-1C-F3-D4
00-26-C7-C6-68-0C
00-73-8D-02-CD-95
E0-2A-82-11-C2-96
0C-71-5D-B1-9A-CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would humbly suggest that you abandon the `.QueryTables` in favor of an `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object for your web page scraping. There is nothing faster and cleaner in VBA's arsenal for retrieving web data.

> This code requires that you add the **Microsoft HTML Object Library** to your project through the VBE's Tools ► References command.

```
Sub retrieveMAC()
    Dim htmlBDY As New HTMLDocument
    Dim m As String, u As String, rw As Long, iTD As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        For rw = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            m = UCase(Replace(Left$(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, 8), Chr(45), vbNullString))
            u = "http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=" & m
            With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                On Error Resume Next
                .Open "GET", u, False
                .Send

                If .Status <> 200 Then
                    Debug.Print .Status
                    GoTo CleanUp
                End If

                htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = vbNullString
                htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                With htmlBDY
                    For iTD = 0 To (.getElementsByTagName("td").Length - 1)
                        With .getElementsByTagName("td")(iTD)
                            If UCase(.innerText) = m Then
                                ws.Cells(rw, 9) = .NextSibling.innerText
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End With
                    Next iTD
                End With

            End With
        Next rw
    End With
CleanUp:
    Set htmlBDY = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Just have simple problem... I need full table with all headings and information.[Prefix Vendor
C0CB38 Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.] I don't want it has to be in the same row where mac id it belongs to. One by one below... Thats enough

Comment: Is anyone please help me. I need the entire table to be downloaded

Comment: Hay!!! I'm sorry if it really hurts you... I need the entire table to be downloaded... I'm feeling guilty that you felt bad... because previously you helped me a lot ... I'll try to delete my account I hope that would helps you... I'm asking again sorry for hurting you :( :(

Comment: There are numerous examples of retrieving a table from a web page on this site. I've given you the framework you need to connect properly and locate the table that you are looking for. There should be no problem expanding on this to get all of the information you are seeking.